# Need of different extensions (phtml, cshtml, etc) in views

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, file-extension

I have worked in a PHP project with `.phtml` files, that means the view contains PHP code and the same goes with a ASP.NET project with the respective `.cshtml` files that contain C# code. So far so good. However, I never wondered if those extensions, also serve some other purposes. Can someone shed some light and explain the use of those extensions?

For example, in a PHP app with some framework,  if some backend code is needed in the view, that code would be in PHP, so why we need to specify a `.phtml` extension instead of just `.html`, in our view files?

Answer (score 2):

So technically, we can make any file extension parse in any language we want. For example, if I wanted all `.html` files to be able to render using PHP I would use something like the following in my httpd.conf (or htaccess if I had the permissions).

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

In regards to the `.phtml` and `.cshtml` it's most likely that these file extensions are already mapped to render using the appropriate language/framework, meaning it's already done for you and you don't have to manually do it yourself (just as I don't have to map `.php` files to render using the PHP framework).